# Why Keras produces dimension error during denses with my code?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Hello I am currently making some simple NN but there are some problems that I don't know why.

The code looks like this

```
import csv
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(123)  # for reproducibility

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
from keras.layers import Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.utils import np_utils
from keras.datasets import mnist

f = open('training.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8')
rdr = csv.reader(f)

X_train = list()
Y_train = list()

print(type(X_train))
for ele in rdr :
    # print(type(ele))
    # print(type(ele[0]))
    X_train.append([float(ele[0])])
    Y_train.append([float(ele[1])])
# reshaping the datas

X_train = np.asarray(X_train)
Y_train = np.asarray(Y_train)

print(X_train.shape)
X_train_1 = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], 1,1)
print(X_train_1.shape)

# print(X_train.shape)
# defining models
model = Sequential()
# model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(4, activation='relu',input_shape=((1, 1))))
print ("model.output_shape1: ", model.output_shape)
# model.add(Dropout(0.5))
# print("Hello")
# print(model.input_shape)
# model.add(Dense(4, activation='softmax'))
# model.add(Dense(1, activation='softmax'))
# print(model.input_shape)

# 8. Compile model
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# 9. Fit model on training data
model.fit(X_train, Y_train, 
          batch_size=32, nb_epoch=10, verbose=0)

# 10. Evaluate model on test data
score = model.evaluate(X_train_1, Y_train, verbose=0)

# print (problem)
# print (answer)

f.close()
```

the error message was

> expected dense_1_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape
>   (863, 1)

the problem is I think I made my X_train_1 array into available shape before entering to NN what did I do wrong?

Also, if I increase the dimension 1 more time by

> X_train_1 = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], 1,1, 1)

then there are errors like

> expected dense_1_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape
>   (863, 1,1, 1)

It seems that I can't make 3 demension array What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input dim id 1. First number in (863, 1) is a number of samples.

Error message

> expected dense_1_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape
>   (863, 1)

suggests that your input is a list of 863 float numbers shaped (1,) please try to change the input shape to input_shape=(1,) or input_dim=1

IF you would like to reshape your data please take a look at this code:

```
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Flatten


X_train = list()
Y_train = list()

for ele in range(0,10):
    X_train.append([float(ele)])
    Y_train.append([float(ele)])

# reshaping the data
X_train = np.asarray(X_train)
Y_train = np.asarray(Y_train)


X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], 1, 1)
print(X_train.shape)
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(4, activation='relu', input_shape=(1, 1)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1, activation='softmax'))

# 8. Compile model
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
#
# # 9. Fit model on training data
model.fit(X_train, Y_train,
          batch_size=32, epochs=10, verbose=1)
```

I had to change it a bit but it shows the way you should reshape your data.

Please notice that I had to flatten the data in order to match the output shape. I also changed loss to binary_crossentropy as my output is a binary data. If you would like to classify to multiple classes you'll have to one hot your output.

Comment: But what about shape (863, 1,1, 1) issues? I am aware that my input is dim 1 but if I change like that then the input dimensions jump to 3 TT

Comment: Of course! But I am new here how can I accept it? Is it OK to just press upward point right next it?

Comment: This link may help: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work